# Give a name to a cell in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-named-ranges

Excel has a little box on the upper left corner that displays the name of the cell (for example `A8`, `C20`, `BC104`, ...) and this name can be changed to a string of choice (like `Force`, `mass`, `acc`, ...) so that when one wants to do a calculation in some cell, one doesn't have to enter the meaningless default names (e.g. `=A8*C20`), but one can enter the specified names (e.g. `=mass*acc`).

How can I do this in Google Sheets?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You'll want to make use of Named Ranges. In this case, the range of cells is one.

1. Select your cell
2. Toolbar → Data → Named ranges... (or right-click on cell and select **Define named range**)

   On the right you will notice a new *Named ranges* sidebar appear
   [image: named ranges sidebar]
3. Edit out "NamedRange1" to whatever you prefer to name the cell
4. Double-check the cell reference below your new cell name is correct
5. Click **Done**

Now you can use that reference to point to that cell instead of having to use the row:column reference.

Comment: NOTE: Then the named range will be available, just like a cell name. So you can write formulas like so now, `=42*NamedRange1 `

Comment: As of 2023 (probably sooner) you can click on a cell and type a name in the "name box" just like the original poster was used to in Excel. This defines a Named Range, just like in the Named Ranges sidebar. You can press CTRL+J to jump to the Name box as you're working.

Answer (score -3):

Excel has a little box on the upper left corner that displays the name of the cell (for example "A8").

This feature is particularly useful for type a certain formula function else where you might use A8 contend.

However, Google Sheets, in contrast with Excel, doesn´t display such Label. Thus Google Sheets prevent users to check where the arrow is on.

Comment: Nowadays Google Sheets has this "little box"